# Google chrome driver not working with google chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I was running some Python selenium tests using google chrome 113.0.5672.63 and google chrome browser. But after google automatically upgrade my browser version to 113.0.5672.93, all my test broke and cannot run anymore. Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: are they not running anymore or what is the problem you are facing

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of your situation is having an old version of `selenium` installed.

If you run:

```bash
pip install -U selenium
```

...then that will upgrade your `selenium` to the latest version, and likely fix your issue. More debugging details would be helpful if that doesn't solve things for you.